# Place Autocomplet (AutocompleteSupportFragment)

Tags: android, google-maps-api, google-places-api

В своей программе использую **AutocompleteSupportFragment**

В [инструкции developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/start) написано, что нужно использовать библиотеку ниже:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:1.0.0'
}
```

После добавления делаю *sync project* - выдает ошибку:

> ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.android.libraries.places:1.0.0:
>   Install Repository and sync project Affected Modules: app

Нажимаю *Install Repository and sync project* - выдает диалогое окно с сообщением:

> Could not find dependency "com.google.android.libraries.places:1.0.0:"

Помогите кто чем может.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка была в инструкции для разработчиков.

Ответ на мой вопрос скрывется под этой [ссылкой](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54484585/googles-new-places-library-implementation-com-google-android-libraries-place)

Ну или для тех кто не хочет проходить по ссылке

эту зависимость:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:1.0.0'
```

нужно заменить этой:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:1.0.0'
```

Надеюсь это кому-то поможет.